# Type Inference with Deconstruct tuple assignment extension methods

Tags: c#, tuples, extension-methods, type-inference

Given some extension methods:

```
public static TO ConvertValue<TI, TO>(TI value) => (TO)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TO));

public static void Deconstruct<TI, TO1, TO2>(this IEnumerable<TI> src, out TO1 p1, out TO2 p2) {
    var e = src.GetEnumerator();
    p1 = e.MoveNext() ? ConvertValue<TI,TO1>(e.Current) : default(TO1);
    p2 = e.MoveNext() ? ConvertValue<TI,TO2>(e.Current) : default(TO2);
}
```

Why is it that the C# compiler is unable to infer the types for `Deconstruct` here:

```
(double p1, int p2) = new int[] {  1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

But has no problem inferring the types here?

```
Ext.Deconstruct(new int[] {  1, 2, 3 }, out int p3, out double p4);
```

Comment: You're not calling `Deconstruct` in the first snippet?

Comment: @Blorgbeard In C# 7.0, a tuple assignment is an implicit call to a `Deconstruct` method (which can be an extension method) on the rhs with the tuple items being the `out` parameters to the `Deconstruct` method when the rhs is not a tuple.).

Comment: Oh, I see. Wasn't aware of that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [deconstructions (C# 7.0) documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/deconstruction.md#resolution-of-the-deconstruct-method) :

None of the parameters can be type arguments.

> The resolution is equivalent to typing rhs.Deconstruct(out var x1, out
>   var x2, ...); with the appropriate number of parameters to deconstruct
>   into. It is based on normal overload resolution. This implies that rhs
>   cannot be dynamic and that none of the parameters of the Deconstruct
>   method can be type arguments. A Deconstruct(out T x1, out T x2)
>   method will not be found.

Comment: That seems straightforward but it also says "The .Net framework also includes a set of System.Tuple types. Those are not recognized as C# tuples, and so will rely on the Deconstruct pattern. Those Deconstruct methods will be provided as extension methods for System.Tuple for up to 3 nestings deep (that is 21 elements)." [Those methods are generic and the parameters are type arguments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tupleextensions.deconstruct?view=netframework-4.7#System_TupleExtensions_Deconstruct__2_System_Tuple___0___1____0____1__). Are those methods a special case?

Comment: I suspect the first sentence is probably more operative. The compiler needs to be able to infer the type parameters without looking at the specified types in the declaration on the left hand side of the deconstruction. That makes sense. In the case of System.Tuple all generic type arguments can be inferred from the first tuple argument. In this example, the compiler actually needs the types from the left hand side to figure out what the generic type argument are. For example `Ext.Deconstruct(new int[] {  1, 2, 3 }, out var p3, out var p4);` would fail to compile as well.

Comment: You are correct. Looking at [TupleExtensions source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ValueTuple/src/System/ValueTuple/TupleExtensions.cs), type has been inferred from first tuple argument.

Comment: @mikez Why do you think that makes sense? I would have thought a translation that including any specified types would make the most sense. In any case, that's too bad for my implementation of a Perl unpack.

Comment: @NetMage I guess it makes sense from what I've read about the design of C#. As a general rule, the language tries to give every expression a type and that information flows outwards. Only in certain very specific circumstances does it flow "inwards". This is because the "inwards" flow is expensive to compute, governed by complex rules that are difficult to understand, and makes error reporting difficult. That said the compiler does it in similar cases like lambda expressions. I can only speculate that it was judged a "nice to have" that could be added later in this case.

Comment: @AkashKC the link to "TupleExtensions source code" returns HTTP 404. [TupleExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/TupleExtensions.cs) might be a better link.

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens' Seems that I can't edit the comment. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: @MikeZboray Years later :) It seems to me that it is the decision to use `out var` would instead of using the user provided specific types is what makes this different from normal generic method type resolution, and I still don't see a justification for ignoring that information.