# c# deconstructors type inference

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, c#-7.0

C# 7.0 introduced deconstructors and we're able to create them for existing classes/interfaces using extension methods.

I've created some IList deconsructor methods

```
    public static void Deconstruct<TValue, TCollection>(this TCollection array, out TValue first, out TCollection rest)
        where TCollection : IList<TValue>, new()
    {
        first = array[0];
        rest = GetRestOfCollection<TValue, TCollection>(array, 1);
    }

    public static void Deconstruct<TValue, TCollection>(this TCollection array, out TValue first, out TValue second)
        where TCollection : IList<TValue>, new()
    {
        if (array.Count != 2)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(@"Collection.Count != 2");

        first = array[0];
        second = array[1];
    }        

    private static TCollection GetRestOfCollection<TValue, TCollection>(TCollection array, int skip)
        where TCollection : IList<TValue>, new() => new TCollection().AddRange(array.Skip(skip));
```

I've tried to use it with deconstruction syntax

```
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

(int team1Score, int team2Score) = ints ;
```

But it it produces

`Error CS8129: No suitable Deconstruct instance or extension method was found for type 'List<int>', with 2 out parameters and a void return type.`

and

`Error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'ListExtensions.Deconstruct<TValue, TCollection>(TCollection, out TValue, out TCollection)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

The only working option is direct call `score.Deconstruct(out var team1,out int team2)` , but this eliminates deconstructor syxtex benefits, as I could use any method for this end.

So why compiler can't find suitable `Deconstruct method`? It's seems obvious to select `public static void Deconstruct<TValue, TCollection>(this TCollection array, out TValue first, out TValue second)`

Comment: Real duplicate is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46840305/5311735. Anyway, if you want this to work - use `Deconstruct(this IList<TValue> array, ...)`